# Soft-Supersymmetry Mass (Direct contact term)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, supersymmetry

I found this term/operator in some papers that can generate masses, e.g [Riva-Biggio-Pomarol(2012)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4526), [Fox-Nelson-Weiner](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0206096)

$\int d^4\theta \frac{X^\dagger X}{M^2}Q^\dagger Q$

Could anyone explain about this term? 
Is there any references that explain this term?

Answer (score 0):

The term give a mass for the squarks. This is easy to see by expanding the superfields,
\begin{equation} 
\frac{ F ^4 }{ M ^4 }\int \,d^4\theta \bar{\theta} ^2 \theta ^2  \left( \tilde{q} ^\dagger + \bar{\theta} \bar{q}  + ... \right) \left( \tilde{q} + \theta q + ... \right) 
\end{equation} 
Only the first squark-squark term survives giving,
\begin{equation} 
m _{ \tilde{q} } ^2 \tilde{q} ^\dagger \tilde{q} 
\end{equation} 
where $ m _{ \tilde{q} } ^2 \equiv F ^4 / M ^4 $ (there is an implicit numerical coefficient outfront as well).